# UIViewController autolayout infinite content

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I have a viewcontroller created via storyboard, but the content in the viewcontroller is dynamic, it can have a lot of data or practically none, the problem is that when the content is a lot the data isn't showing because its bigger than the viewcontroller or the screen height, is there a way to set like a UIScrollView so that when the data in the controller exceeds the screen height i can simply scroll down or up?, thanks in advance.

i mean, for example, normally the screen should look like this:

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PuBhu.png)

but sometimes it looks like this:

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B089o.png)

as you can see the when the info exceeds the screen height, i can't see the data correctly

Comment: Are you talking about scrolling up and down in the app or in the storyboard? No scrolling in the storyboard; scroll views only scroll in "real life".

Comment: I made an edit explaining better the situation

Comment: Yes, you can use a scroll view, and that might be a good solution, but your question is too broad to be answered well.

Comment: Use `UIScrollView` or views subclassed from `UIScrollView` such as `UITableView` or `UICollectionView`.

Comment: What do you mean that is too broad? do yo need more explicit explanation @picciano?

Comment: A literal answer to your question would be "Yes, you can use a scroll view", however, a more useful answer would read more like a tutorial on how to implement that, which does not fit well with the question-answer format on SO. Perhaps begin the process of implementing the scroll view and come back and ask specific questions if you run into issues doing so, or even better, find answers to questions already asked. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends what type of data it is. I suggest for your case to use a `UIScrollView`, which will allow you to scroll up or down.

[image]